# Cache Refresh Stuck At 100%

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, update-manager, asus

I've been trying to update my software to the latest version, but after I opened Software Updater, it shows **Failed to download repository information**. After that, I headed to Software & Updates. After making some changes, it showed that my software cache is out dated and needs to be refreshed. After I pressed yes, it opened the Cache Refresh window. After it ran to 100% (I think) an Ubuntu error report window pops up. After that, it stuck. Is it a bug? Or is it just my computer?

[image: The window]

Comment: By the way, I forget to mention that I'm connect to a stable network and there weren't any install process running in the background. I'm using an ASUS laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 installed

Comment: Please manually run ```sudo apt update``` in the terminal and post the results.It might be a problem about reaching the servers.And please add changes and edits to your original post via the [edit button](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1252716/edit).Don't use comments for that purpose.

Comment: But that doesn't work @ParsaMousavi

Comment: What's the error that ```sudo apt update``` shows you ?

Comment: E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubu... focal Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423) focal Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease' is not signed.
@ParsaMousavi

Comment: So make a backup of your ```/etc/apt/sources.list``` file and copy-paste [this](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/JjsZWtPgWS/). That's the standard sources file for ubuntu 20.04.Then run ```sudo apt update``` again.

Comment: I think the problem is that you added a wrong PPA for WineHQ.The ubuntu 20.04 codename is **FOCAL** , not eoan.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Thank you, that solution really do works! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the standard `/etc/apt/sources.list` file :

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
```

Copy-paste it after making a backup of your current `source.list` file then run `sudo apt update`.And also when you want to add a PPA note that the codename of the ubuntu 20.04 is **FOCAL** not **eoan** which is **19.10**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue in Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS, and just go to *software & update* -> *Software Ubuntu* tab and choose **Main server** from  *Download from:*
[image]